# Cómo seleccionar una etiqueta que se encuentra dentro un div padre sin query selector

Tags: javascript

Necesito encontrar una manera de seleccionar una etiqueta que se encuentra dentro de un div que si tiene clase, ya probé usando query selector pero parece que no funciona en el sitio, y no puedo alterar esto ya que el sitio web no es mio.

```js
// YA POBRÉ CON ESTOS Y AUNQUE NO ME DA ERRORES NO FUNCIONA EN EL SITIO
var product = document.querySelector(".padre > h2 > a");
var produc = document.querySelectorAll(".padre > h2 > a");

// LA UNICA QUE ME FUNCIONA ES ESTA PERO NO PUEDO ACCEDER AL CONTENIDO DENTRO SOLO AL DIV 
var prod = document.getElementsByClassName("padre");
```

```html
<div class="padre">
<h2>
<a href="#">Producto</a>
</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Puedes agregar un enlace al sitio web indicando donde tienes que seleccionar el `<a>`?

Comment: El código que compartes y el primer script son funcionales y si devuelven el valor de la etiqueta los acabo de probar

Comment: @Aprendiz también los probé en w3 y funcionan pero en el sitio web no, es lo que me interesa saber por qué

Comment: Hola @NuevoUsuario, estuve realizando pruebas con `var product = document.querySelector(".padre > h2 > a");` y `var produc = document.querySelectorAll(".padre > h2 > a");`. El primero captura el elemento, mientras que el segundo no. De hecho, el segundo causa problemas y puede invalidar el resto del código. En el supuesto que lo estés utilizando y te funcione en cualquier lado, menos en el sitio Web que mencionas puede deberse al código **HTML** cargándose antes del **script**. De todas maneras, puedes compartir el enlace de la página para analizar por qué presenta el inconveniente planteado.

Answer (score 0):

Podirás acceder al elemento que mencionas con:

```
var prod = document.getElementsByClassName("padre")[0].childNodes
```

y ahi seleccionar le que necesites